# Do we have 2 minutes of extra morning?

Tags: visible-light, geophysics, refraction, atmospheric-science

my physics teacher told me about the refraction and its applications one of them was
**2 minutes of early sunrise** and after she explained this effect she concluded that days are
**2 minutes longer** than one would naively presume.

However, I think that **her conclusion is wrong** because
**if sunrise is considered then sunset should also be considered** and according to me **sunsets should be 2 minutes late** therefore **the day time is increased by 4 minutes and not 2 minutes** over the naive calculation.

According to me, the situation looks something like this:
[image]
Is this idea of mine correct or not? And if we both are wrong, then what should be the right conclusion and why ?

Comment: Your image, of course, should have the south pole in the centre. But that's hardly important.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are correct. The sun is still/already below the horizon at the time of apparent sunrise/sunset, and each of these effects will extend the length of each day by exactly the same  amount because the situation is completely symmetrical.

Well caught!

Comment: Strictly speaking, the situation is not exactly symmetrical: 1) the length of the day depends on the declination of the sun, which changes slightly between sunrise and sunset; 2) the refraction of the atmosphere depends on atmospheric conditions; 3) the earth is not an exact spheroid. But these effects are very small.